# SQL: rank over error or use count?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to achieve this result :

[image]

and my 2 tables are transactional order table: `orderdate`, `country`, `month`, `valid order`. 2nd table : `customer id`, `new member` and `segment`.

I have tried this code below :

```
SELECT 
    Distinct od.orderdate AS orderdate, od.country AS country,
    od.month ,c.cust_id as customerid
    Rank over () ( Partition by c.cust_id order by od.orderdate DESC) as rank
FROM 
    order_transaction_table as od
    INNER JOIN customertable as c
ON 
    od.cust_id=c.cust_id
    AND od.country=c.country
WHERE 
    od.country=2
    AND od.month between 201701 and 201711
    AND od.valid_order=1
    AND c. country = 2
    AND c.month between 201701 and 201711
    AND c.new member =1
    AND c.segment = 1
ORDER BY 
    od.month;
```

I keep on hitting errors that the codes above wont work. I am unsure where did I go wrong. I tried the command 'count on c.custid' but it doesn't work out too. 
Appreciate someone can help. Thank you!

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: “From keyword not found where expected” I am using sql to run @ spss.

Comment: `Rank over () ( Partition order c.cust_id by od.orderdate DESC) as rank` that's not the syntax? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql `PARTITION BY` at a minimum... `RANK() OVER (...)` too...

Comment: @ta.speot.is. Hi, I just run the syntax it still fails. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

Just to solve the issue on the RANK
query should be

```
Rank () over (Partition by  c.cust_id order by od.orderdate DESC) as rank
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I have rerun using the suggestion but it showed similar error. I guess somewhere the logic has gone wrong. Let me edit the syntax above.

Comment: Hi, yes I have just done it. But it is not producing any result.

Comment: that's your next problem. my solution is for the rank

Comment: Hi, do not think it is due to syntax. Thanks anyway.